# Перевод выражения

Tags: перевод

(Мне не приходит на ум лучшее заглавие. Если у вас какая-то идея, поправите её, пожалуйста)

В книжке В. Березина "Путевые знаки" я прочитал

> Я **выбираюсь** наружу, и воздушный поток тут же срывает у меня с головы пилотку. Это отцовская пилотка (...) Пилотка мне велика, но я **берегу её пуще коллекции вкладышей от жвачки**.

Проблема у меня прежде всего в словах отмеченных жирным шрифтом.

Я не уверен в том, или я хорошо понимаю смысл этого отрывка. По-моему можно бы это так перевести:

> I'm getting out to the edge and the stream of the air takes my pilot cap from my head at this very place. It's my father's cap (...) The cap is too big for me but I protect it worse than my collection of chewing gums

Особенно второе жирное предложение звучит странно. Перевёл ли я правильно?

Кстати, почему в первом предложении чистой дательный падеж *(наружу)* а не с предлогом *(к наружу)*

Comment: There is an adverbial *кнаружи* meaning *from the inside towards the outside* but it cannot be used in a positional sense and is rarely used outside medical jargon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Я выбираюсь наружу = I am going out

Наружу - it is a direction "(kind of moving) out", not place or point or zone.

Снаружи - it is zone "out of", "outside".

There is no word "наружи", so you couldn't say "к наружи".

2. Пилотка мне вилка, но я берегу её пуще коллекции вкладышей от жвачки.

a) I think not "вилка", but "велик**а**" - It has a size larger than I needed.

b) берегу - беречь = to save, to keep

c) жвачка = жевательная резинка = chewing gum

жвачка = short slang form

d) вкладыш, коллекция вкладышей = pic: http://vk.cc/3Tymh2

about collecting:

In 90-th, when USSR was crashed, wide import of goods started. There was a lot of chewing gum. Every boy tried to collect full set of these pictures. Turbo - cars (first set was of 120, second set of 450 pictures), Bombibom - also cars, TipTip - comix, Love Is - one picture comix, and so on. There was a kind of school gambling when you put two pictures facedown one on another on the table or floor or windowsill and try to turn them faceup by beating them by open hand. If you turn both you get them (yours and the other's). It was very respectful to have full collection of "Turbo" pics.

* excuse my English)))

e) So, character saves this cap more than this collection.

Comment: So *cuuute* explanation on d) , I'm touched.

Answer (score 2):

«наружу» was historically the Accusative of an obsolete noun «[ружь](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fshare%2Fstarling%2Fmorpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8C&method_word=substring&ic_word=on&text_general=&method_general=substring&ic_general=on&text_origin=&method_origin=substring&ic_origin=on&text_trubachev=&method_trubachev=substring&ic_trubachev=on&text_editorial=&method_editorial=substring&ic_editorial=on&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&ic_pages=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=word&ic_any=on)» with the preposition *на*
(«на ружу»), not the Dative. 
Nowadays it is used only as an adverb and written in one word.

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце.

`Я выбираюсь наружу` = Я выхожу на улицу, I am getting out [into the open]
`выбираюсь` здесь может означать, что выход на улицу чем-то затруднён, требует усилий, или автор провёл много времени в помещении (или ещё где-то, где можно быть «внутри»).
`наружу` (*out*) — наречие, у него нет падежей.
`пуще` = сильнее, больше, *more than*
`вкладыши` — небольшие листочки бумаги с картинками, например, из комиксов или мультиков, которые могли быть в упаковке жвачки. Яркие и привлекательные, могли быть ценным объектом собирания/коллекционирования (детьми), а также атрибутом недоступного Запада в советские времена.

Comment: Контекст такой, что всё происходит в самолёте. http://loveread.ws/read_book.php?id=3416&p=1, поищи "наружу"

Answer (score 1):

пуще = сильнее, больше.

```
пуще прежнего - more than before  
он боится его пуще смерти — he fears him more than death
```

There's also a traditional (folklore) rhyme. I think, it originated long ago as a rain-calling spell. Such rhymes are called "[закличка](http://sadikshkola.ru/zaklichki-dozhdyu)", from "кликать" - to call for:

```
Дождик, дождик, пуще!
Чтоб росла пшеница гуще,
Чтоб овёс рос и ячмень -
Поливай весь день!
А на просо, на рожь
Поливай сколько хошь!
```

Here "пуще" means "rain more, spill more water"

The word "пуще" is quite obsolete, so I recommend not to use it in speech.

Answer (score 0):

I get outside, and the air stream sweeps the field cap off my head at that very moment. That field cap once belonged to my dad... The field cap is too big for me, but I keep it with even more care than I do with my collected inlay pics from chewing gum packages.

("велика", not "вилка")

For title: Signs On My Way.